# Converting decimal degrees to state plane in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, feature-class, state-plane

I'm working in Arcmap 10.1 and I have a point feature class that I already have xy values in decimal degrees. The projection is state plane. The feature class also has two fields for the state plane that I need converted from the decimal degrees.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

[Calculating area, length, and other geometric properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm) in the Online Help has the instructions.

1. Bring the data into ArcMap.
2. Set the projection to State Plane.
3. Open the Attribute Table.
4. right click on the state plane x field (or add it)
5. Select calculate geometry
6. Select the X coridinate and the state plane projection and it will calculate the x in state plane.
7. repeat for y.